# Google plus determine changes in network

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to determine changes in the Google+ network in an efficient manner (profile changes). My first idea was to use the eTags of the People.List and People.Get. My assumption was that the eTag in the List (person) would be the same as the one in the Get. This is not the case!

I rather not want to get the details of all the people in the network and checking the eTag for each of them. I will run out of daily api-calls very quickly using that scenario.

Are there any other ways of determining the changes in the network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to notify your service when changes occur on a user's profile. I don't think that etags will work for what you are trying to do and the client libraries should already be using the etags to manage any query caching. You can perform a few tricks to make queries lighter on your backend though:

- [Batch API calls](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/04/batching-calls-to-google-apis-javascript.html)
- Use a [fields filter](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=%252BGusClass&collection=public&fields=items%252Fobject%252Fattachments%252Fimage%252Furl&_h=1&) to just only get the data that matters for your application

If you are running out of quota, you can also request to have your limits raised from the Google APIs console by clicking the Quotas link on the left. The developer relations team from Google+ checks the request regularly and will raise your quota limits if your usage justifies it.

Comment: Okay, implemented the Batch calls, but it still feels strange to not be able to detect any changes. I guess there is still some room of improvement in the API. For instance: LinkedIn provides a parameter which gives you the changes after a certain date. Facebook provides an callback mechanism which is called when a profile changes.

Comment: @PatrickVorgers Those are some great suggestions!  Please add or star them in the issue tracker so that the Google+ team can factor in your suggestions into the platform. https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/